# FFmpeg script to convert all WebM files in a folder to Gif, and then delete the WebM files

Tags: ffmpeg, script, conversion, gif, webm

I'm using FFmpeg with DirectoryMonitor, a folder watching program. When a webm is added to the folder i want to execute a script to convert all webm files in that folder to gif, and then delete those webm files.

I'm on windows 10.

Comment: Is there a certain way you want it setup? like it watches a certain folder then coverts whatever you you put in the folder to .gif?

Comment: Yup. Failing that, converting and deleting everything until the only webm files left to convert are new ones will work.